# Altering diagonal entries of a square matrix to get simple eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Is there a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A + D$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: it is very likely there is. the char poly is of degree $n$ so you must be able to adjust the $n$ coefficients by choosing the $n$ diagonal entries to make $n$ distinct eigenvalues. this is just a hunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The diagonal matrix $\operatorname{Diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)$ obviously has distinct eigenvalues. Since the eigenvalues depend continuously on the matrix entries¹, for a small enough $\varepsilon > 0$ the matrix $\varepsilon A + \operatorname{Diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)$ still has distinct eigenvalues.

Since a nonzero scalar multiple of a matrix with distinct eigenvalues again has distinct eigenvalues, this will be true about
$$ A + \operatorname{Diag}(1/\varepsilon,2/\varepsilon,\ldots,n/\varepsilon)$$

¹: This is a bit handwavy, but can be made rigorous with a bit of elbow grease. For a *real* matrix an easier argument would be that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial depend continuously on the matrix entries, so adding a sufficiently small multiple of $A$ won't change the alternating *signs* of the characteristic polynomial at $\frac12, \frac32, \frac52, \ldots, \frac{2n+1}2$ -- so $\varepsilon A + \operatorname{Diag}(...)$ must still have $n$ different eigenvalues.

---

Almost certainly a $D$ with small *random* diagonal entries will also work (assuming that complex eigenvalues count), but that seems to be less easy to prove.

Comment: that is nice and easy.